# Transiting Amsterdam with single entry Schengen visa for Norway?

Tags: schengen, transit, amsterdam, norway, fijian-citizens

I hold a Fiji Passport and I have obtained a Schengen Visa for Norway. It is a short stay visa and is for single entry only.

I will be transiting Amsterdam while going to Norway; will my Schengen short stay visa for single entry in Norway be sufficient to guarantee me an air-side transit in Amsterdam?

Comment: @Gagravarr It's not really a duplicate, since the question is different.

Comment: I am pretty sure we have some related questions somewhere but not the one linked as a duplicate (this one is about using a visa, not applying for one).

Answer (score 4):

Actually, the rules for airside transit do not apply. You will simply enter the Schengen area in Amsterdam. After that, you won't have any entries left on your visa but you can still fly to Norway. By contrast, you could not go to the UK and reenter the Schengen area, even if you just wanted to transit airside in the UK.

As far as the number of entries is concerned, you could therefore just as well leave the airport, spend a week in Amsterdam and fly to Norway after that or even tour several Schengen countries before reaching Norway. As it's all part of the Schengen area, there would only be one entry. For non-stop flights between the Netherlands and Norway, there won't be any border check or stamping of your passport and a single-entry visa is therefore sufficient.

Comment: Does single entry visa mean that i can visit only 1 schengen country? OR does it mean that i can visit many schengen countries BUT can not revisit those countries again because the visa says single entry Only. Did i get this correct?

Comment: "Actually, the rules for airside transit do not apply. You will simply enter the Schengen area in Amsterdam. After that, you won't have any entries left on your visa but you can still fly to Norway." I will be returning for transit in amsterdam while returning back to my country - so no visa issues in transit right despite I have visited amsterdam in my earlier flight?

Comment: @Smoothie One entry is one entry in the whole area, there are no restrictions on the number of countries or the number of times you visit a given country on a regular Schengen visa and no way to track your trips between countries. You can think of the whole area as a single country. On the way back, the same principle applies, you won't leave the Schengen area or get an exit stamp before Amsterdam (the trip from Norway and the time in Amsterdam do count in your Schengen stay as well).